# How to use single sign on with ODBC?

Tags: postgresql, oauth, odbc, single-sign-on, cas

I am looking for a single sign on approach for an ODBC connection to a Postgres database.

The plan is to login to a web application and then use a a single sign on scheme such as oauth or CAS to automatically login to a client application.

The client application does not verify the credentials itself, but uses them via ODBC to connect to the Postgres database server. Unlike web applications we cannot use a single databaes user here, but need individual database accounts for security reasons.

In theory Postgres does support PAM and PAM supports both CAS and oauth. But I was not able to find any documentation on that. Especially the part of how to specify the token in ODBC is unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

With PAM auth, keep in mind that this is a broad field and books could be written about it.  I do something similar to what you do though and can answer the part about ODBC.  The following provides a walkthrough for a related service you may find helpful:

http://www.wikidsystems.com/support/wikid-support-center/how-to/how-to-secure-postgresql-using-two-factor-authentication-from-wikid

The big thing to remember is that with PAM the password provided is passed on to the PAM module, so you have to pass in the username and password.  This gets sent to PAM as if the user was logging on to the system.  Beyond that it's up to you to configure PAM appropriately for your service.